# How to convert scala Array of Maps into Spark df

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I having scala array of type `Array[Map[String,String]]` and i want to convert it into spark df.

input:-
`Array(Map("col1" -> "val1"), Map("col2" -> "val2", "col1" -> "val1"), Map("col3" -> "val3") )`

expected output:-

Spark df

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| val1 | NA | NA |
| val1 | val2 | NA |
| NA | NA | val3 |

What is best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

First extract the keys:

```
val input = Seq(Map("col1" -> "val1"), Map("col2" -> "val2", "col1" -> "val1"), Map("col3" -> "val3"))
val keys = input.flatMap(_.keys.toSeq).distinct
```

you will then need a method to fill all the non existing keys on each Map object with null as follows:

```
def completeNonExistingValuesWithNull(obj: Map[String, String])(columnNames: String*): Map[String, String] = {
  val nonExistingKeys = columnNames.filterNot(obj.keys.toSeq.contains)
  obj concat Map(
    nonExistingKeys.map { key =>
      key -> (null: String)
    }: _*
  )
}
// I would also rather creating a function value to use in
// map functions easily so I wont need to pass the keys everytime
val completeNonExistingValues: Map[String, String] => Map[String, String] = 
    obj => completeNonExistingValuesWithNull(obj)(keys: _*)
```

One other thing you need, is to be able to convert sequences to tuples in order to create rows for your dataframe (since sequence objects are counted as a single object with ArrayType struct)

```
def toProduct(seq: Seq[String]) = seq match {
  case Seq(a, b, c) => (a, b, c)
}
```

and it's done:

```
val completedKeyValues: Seq[Map[String, String]] =
  input.map(completeNonExistingValues)

val objects = completedKeyValues.map(_.values.toSeq).map(toProduct)

import spark.implicits._
objects.toDF(keys: _*)
```